# When using google's auth2 api, is it possible to submit a nonce or state

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, openid-connect

I'm using [Google Sign-in for websites api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignin) and would like to submit a nonce and have it returned in the signed JWT id_token (in the JTI field).

The [google identity platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl) mentions both a nonce and a state field, but none of these appear to work with with the auth2 api.  What is the correct way to send and receive this value using auth2?

Comment: What would you like to achieve by passing nonce?

Comment: @agektmr Replay attacks, but primarily I would like to correlate the request and the response.

Comment: If you are talking about OAuth protocol level matter, Google Sign-In library takes care of it and you don't have to worry about nonce.

Comment: @agektmr Not sure I follow.  The client after receiving a request to authenticate, will authenticate with the Google Sign in libraries, receive a token, and send that token to the original application which validates the id_token and correlates the request & response.  Without a nonce/state how is the correlation performed?

Comment: Google Sign-In library can directly connect with Google server and let user signed-in. Your browser will then receive an id_token so you can send that to your server to verify, then authenticate and start a session. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: @agektmr Thanks for the link.  I don't currently have any issue setting up the flow you have suggested.  What I do have a problem with is correlating, the request the server made to the client, with the response the client sends to the server.

What I am confused about, is the Google Identity platform[link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl) (which suggests using Google Sign-In) appears to have the exact parameters required, nonce & state. Are these parameters available to use or have I misunderstood how the api's work with each other.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Google Sign-In is a library to achive exact same thing as what you have read on the link you suggested. It's complex, right? That causes security issues. Our suggestion is to use Google Sign-In library unless you have good reasons. You can ignore nonce, state etc described in that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per discussion from the comments, I see you are trying to mix raw OAuth protocol and Google Sign-In library.
While things mentioned in [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl) such as nonce or state are part of OAuth protocol, Google Sign-In is a JavaScript library that simplifies things down.

With Google Sign-In, you can let users sign in only with JavaScript. If you want to integrate with the server, send `id_token` you can obtain from JS API to the server. Further information can be found in the following resources.

Google Sign-In for Websites:

- docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/
- videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNYkxOF6rcIBQCKXOfi4AUtSpMj78pX5f
- sample code: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/google-sign-in

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems a shame to have to abandon Google Sign-In over the omission of one parameter though.